# Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name

Tags: java, spring

I define a custom gateway filter in spring cloud gateway `2.2.8.RELEASE` like this:

```
package com.dolphin.gateway.filter;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author dolphin
 */
@Component
public class CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CustomAddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig> {

    private final Class<CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig> configClass = CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig.class;

    @Override
    public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("headerName", "headerValue"));
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig config) {
        return ((exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().headers(httpHeaders -> {
                httpHeaders.set(config.getHeaderName(), config.getHeaderValue());
            }).build();
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        });
    }

    @Override
    public ShortcutType shortcutType() {
        return ShortcutType.DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig> getConfigClass() {
        return configClass;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig newConfig() {
        return BeanUtils.instantiateClass(this.configClass);
    }

    public static class CustomAddRequestHeaderConfig {

        private String headerName;
        private String headerValue;

        public String getHeaderName() {
            return headerName;
        }

        public void setHeaderName(String headerName) {
            this.headerName = headerName;
        }

        public String getHeaderValue() {
            return headerValue;
        }

        public void setHeaderValue(String headerValue) {
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and config the gateway filter in `application.properties` like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=CustomAddRequestHeader=customHeaderName,customHeaderValue
```

but when I start the project,shows error like this:

```
   2021-09-21 17:38:46.280 ERROR 1 --- [oundedElastic-6] r.c.s.Schedulers : Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CustomAddRequestHeader
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name CustomAddRequestHeader
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:187) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:233) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:170) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator$$Lambda$929/0x0000000038c53400.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:481) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:414) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.drain(FluxMergeSequential.java:425) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.innerComplete(FluxMergeSequential.java:321) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialInner.onComplete(FluxMergeSequential.java:576) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:262) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:293) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:839) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:601) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.innerComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:887) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:990) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1795) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.commons.publisher.FluxFirstNonEmptyEmitting$FirstNonEmptyEmittingSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFirstNonEmptyEmitting.java:336) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onComplete(FluxSubscribeOn.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2054) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:357) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.3.16.RELEASE.jar!/:3.3.16.RELEASE]
```

where is going wrong? what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that I add the component scan annotation effect the SpringBootApplication package scan, by default the SpringBootApplication annotation would scan the package and sub package with current project namespace.After I added the component scan in the startup class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "misc.exception"
})
```

this will override the SpringBootApplication default package scan, the SpringBootApplication will no longer scan the project namespace package by default, so we should add the package scan explicit in the component scan annotation like this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "misc.exception",
        "com.dolphin.gateway"
})
```

will fix this problem.